# Can't access controller property in nested zf-tabs

Tags: angularjs, zurb-foundation

I have a simple controller for AngularJS:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('MainController', MainController);

    function MainController() {
        var vm = this;
        vm.countries = ["México", "Brasil", "Chile"];
        vm.cities = {
            Mexico: ["Ciudad de México", "Guadalajara", "Monterrey"],
            Brasil: ["Sao Paulo", "Rio de Janeiro", "Porto Alegre"],
            Chile: ["Santiago de Chile", "Valparaiso", "Viña del Mar"]
        };
    }
})();
```

Using Zurb Foundation for apps I want to nest Tabs inside tabs with the next HTML markup:

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
    <div zf-tabs="">
        <div zf-tab="" title="{{country}}" ng-repeat="country in vm.countries">
            <!-- Here I can print the array of countries see all the properties of the country inside the tab -->
            {{$parent.vm.countries}}

            <div zf-tabs="">
                <!-- Here I can't access the scope of my controller see all the cities for each country -->
                <div zf-tab="" title="{{city}}" ng-repeat="city in $parent.vm.cities[$parent.country]">
                    {{city.population}}
                </div>
                <div zf-tab="" title="Test tab">
                    <!-- Here I can't print the array of countries -->
                    {{$parent.$parent.vm.countries}
                </div>
            </div
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However it seems that I can't access the controller Scope from within the second zf-tabs.

Any idea on how I should work with it?

Comment: Does it work if you don't use $parent? I see that you're using controllerAs syntax which should solve this issue.

Comment: No :(... I couldn't use $parent to solve this issue. I finally used my own tab for the nested tab.